# Why does my Excel formula return "cell contains a lambda error"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-lambda

I'm trying to follow the example for lambda in [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/lambda-the-ultimatae-excel-worksheet-function/) post, I tried to type the Name `HEAD` in the `A1` and the formula `=LAMBDA(str,IF(str="","error: HEAD of empty string", LEFT(str,1)))` in `B1`, as per the following GIF.

[image: lambda]

I get a `#CALC!` error.

There does seem to be some functionality I'm unaware of here, as `HEAD` appears to be recognised as `B1` in my formula. However, `B5` reports an 'invalid cell reference` error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Those are just to show what is in the named range.  There is a named range called `HEAD` that has that formula in it.  Then when the named range is called with the reference it works.

Comment: Aah - I think you're right. Not very clear from that example that that's what's going on but I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you may not have the functionality as from the post:  `LAMBDA is available to members of the Insiders: Beta program`.

Comment: Besides that, the article mentioned that *"Reversing a string is beyond the built-in functions of Excel and could only previously be written outside the formula language, by using Visual Basic or JavaScript."* which is simply not true.